# Remove public form URL in Laravel when uploaded on cPanel also always redirect to https://

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, http

so I have uploaded my project to cPanel's **public_html** folder and my URL is
`https://website.com` but my URL looks like`https://website.com/public`
whenever I try to get `https://website.com` some wired URL comes with a 404 or continues loading the page.
so how can I use **.htaccsess** and make it so that my URL `https://website.com/about` look like this, not like this `https://website.com/public/about`

also, i want all my `http://` request to go on `https://`

After finding a lot I found this line but it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`

here is my website's root folder's **.htaccsess** file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Also, make the answer general so that I or anyone can use it in any situation.
and provide any explanation link because I want to learn this.

Comment: To access website without public, just move you **index.php** from public folder to projects root folder and exicute config cache comand.

Comment: @WaqasAltaf no I tried but it's not working.